# How to update and upsert documents in MongoDB (Mongoose). NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a service which get data from server using GET request. I repeat this request every 10 seconds and after every request I save these data to my database. My code attached below. 
But I need filter my new data which I received from server to not repeat data in database. I read that I need to do update in my database with `upset: true` but I guess that I do something incorrect. Could you please help me with this task?
app.js code:

```
const Tenders = require('./libs/mongoose');
const request = require('request');

let url = `http://public.api.openprocurement.org/api/2.4/tenders?offset=${new Date().toISOString()}+02.00`;

function getTenders() {
  request(url, { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    url = `http://public.api.openprocurement.org/api/2.4/tenders?offset=${body.next_page.offset}`;

    const tendersList = [];
    let tendersData = new Tenders({ tenderId: String, tenderDate: String });

    body.data.forEach((item) => {
      tendersData = {
        tenderId: item.id,
        tenderDate: item.dateModified,
      };
      tendersList.push(tendersData);
    });

    Tenders.findAll({ tenderId: tendersData.tenderId }, (err, tenderId) => {
      if (!tenderId) {
        Tenders.insertMany(tendersList)
          .then((item) => {
            console.log('Saved to db');
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      } else {
        console.log('Data is already in db');
      }
    });
  });
}

getTenders();
setInterval(getTenders, 10000);
```

and just in case mongoose.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('../config');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(
  config.get('mongoose:uri'),
  { useMongoClient: true },
);

const tender = new mongoose.Schema({
  tenderId: String,
  tenderDate: String,
});

const Tenders = mongoose.model('Tenders', tender);

module.exports = Tenders;
```

I guess that my code with `Tenders.find....` and `Tenders.insertMany` looks only for one item not all of them. So please, can you help me with inserting my first part of data and after that 'upsert' data in database with new data from server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your insert/update logic can be simplified using update function with upsert flag true

Here is an implementation, (hope `tenderId` is indexed)

```
const TenderSchema = new Schema({ tenderId: String, tenderDate: String });
const Tender = mongoose.model('Tender', TenderSchema, 'tenders');

var tenders = [
    {tenderId :'tender-1', tenderDate : '1-1-2018'},
    {tenderId :'tender-2', tenderDate : '2-1-2018'},
    {tenderId :'tender-3', tenderDate : '3-1-2018'},
    {tenderId :'tender-2', tenderDate : '4-1-2018'},
    {tenderId :'tender-1', tenderDate : '5-1-2018'},
    {tenderId :'tender-2', tenderDate : '4-1-2018'}
];

for (var t of tenders){
    Tender.update(
        {'tenderId' : t.tenderId }, 
        {$set : t}, 
        {upsert : true, multi : true}, 
        function(err, doc){
                if(err) throw err;
                console.log(doc);
        }
    )
}
```

collection

```
> db.tenders.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a5d87d8a5f292efd566d186"), "tenderId" : "tender-1", "__v" : 0, "tenderDate" : "5-1-2018" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a5d87d8a5f292efd566d187"), "tenderId" : "tender-2", "__v" : 0, "tenderDate" : "4-1-2018" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a5d87d8a5f292efd566d188"), "tenderId" : "tender-3", "__v" : 0, "tenderDate" : "3-1-2018" }
>
```

console log

```
saravana@ubuntu:~/node-mongoose$ node so4.js
`open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0, use `openUri()` instead, or set the `useMongoClient` option if using `connect()` or`createConnection()`. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#use-mongo-client
Mongoose: tenders.update({ tenderId: 'tender-1' }, { '$set': { tenderId: 'tender-1', tenderDate: '1-1-2018' }, '$setOnInsert': { __v: 0 } }, { multi: true, upsert: true })
Mongoose: tenders.update({ tenderId: 'tender-2' }, { '$set': { tenderId: 'tender-2', tenderDate: '2-1-2018' }, '$setOnInsert': { __v: 0 } }, { multi: true, upsert: true })
Mongoose: tenders.update({ tenderId: 'tender-3' }, { '$set': { tenderId: 'tender-3', tenderDate: '3-1-2018' }, '$setOnInsert': { __v: 0 } }, { multi: true, upsert: true })
Mongoose: tenders.update({ tenderId: 'tender-2' }, { '$set': { tenderId: 'tender-2', tenderDate: '4-1-2018' }, '$setOnInsert': { __v: 0 } }, { multi: true, upsert: true })
Mongoose: tenders.update({ tenderId: 'tender-1' }, { '$set': { tenderId: 'tender-1', tenderDate: '5-1-2018' }, '$setOnInsert': { __v: 0 } }, { multi: true, upsert: true })
Mongoose: tenders.update({ tenderId: 'tender-2' }, { '$set': { tenderId: 'tender-2', tenderDate: '4-1-2018' }, '$setOnInsert': { __v: 0 } }, { multi: true, upsert: true })
{ n: 1, nModified: 1, ok: 1 }
{ n: 1, nModified: 1, ok: 1 }
{ n: 1, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }
{ n: 1, nModified: 1, ok: 1 }
{ n: 1, nModified: 1, ok: 1 }
{ n: 1, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }
^C
saravana@ubuntu:~/node-mongoose$
```

Comment: yes, I've added index: true to tenderId. and I'll try to use your solution